# How to get an url with collection and model ids

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I made a website to create some maps. So, all my maps have an `id`, and my map has some elements with ids.

So I create a collection Map with an id and its model is my map object :

```
app.collections.mapDetailsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.models.mapDetailsModel,
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.id = options.id;
    },
    url: function () {
        return this.absURL + '/api/maps/' + this.id;
    },
    parse: function(response){
        return response.features;
    },
    toGeoJSON: function(){
        var features = [];
        this.models.forEach(function(model){
            var feature = model.toGeoJSON();
            if (! _.isEmpty(feature.geometry)) {
                features.push(feature);
            }
        });
        return {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': features
        };
    }
});
```

But my model have an id too. I don't know for a model how to return url with a collection id.

I need to return `/api/maps/id_collection/id_model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a model is added to a collection, it receives a reference to the collection. So each model has a collection property `this.collection` set if it's in a collection.

From the Backbone [model constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) documentation (emphasis mine):

> If you pass a `{collection: ...}` as the options, the model gains a
>   `collection` property that will be used to indicate which collection the
>   model belongs to, and is used to help compute the model's [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url). **The
>   `model.collection` property is normally created automatically when you
>   first add a model to a collection.** Note that the reverse is not true,
>   as passing this option to the constructor will not automatically add
>   the model to the collection. Useful, sometimes.

Then, you could use that to build the full url of a model:

```
var app.models.mapDetailsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: function() {
        // Backbone adds the model id automatically
        return this.collection.url() + '/my-model/';
    }
    // ...snip...
});
```

Note that the default url for a model is what you want.

> Generates URLs of the form: `[collection.url]/[id]` by default, but
>   you may override by specifying an explicit `urlRoot` if the model's
>   collection shouldn't be taken into account.